# AWS Lambda (Python) - FCM Integration with Default VPC is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, aws-lambda, pyfcm

I have followed below link and integrated FCM into AWS Lambda (Python) function.

https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM.

Its works fine with no VPC configured. But when I integrate with Lambda method to query RDS using default VPC configured, its not working. Always am getting timeout in FCM send message.

Kindly share if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Did you deploy the Lambda function on a private subnet in the VPC whose default gateway points to a NAT Gateway on a public subnet?  I'm guessing not, since that is a common mistake, and will prevent code in the Lambda function from accessing the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for your response.